# Local-exec with Terraform and AWS CLI inconsistent

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

I am trying to modify DMS S3 Endpoint extra connection attributes with the AWS cli since it does not work within terraform resource.

I have this code:

```
resource "aws_dms_endpoint" "s3_endpoint" {

  count                       = length(var.zones)
  endpoint_id                 = "${var.s3_endpoint_id_prefix}-${var.environment}-${var.shortApp}-${var.zones[count.index]}"
  endpoint_type               = "target"
  engine_name                 = "s3"
  ssl_mode                    = "none"
  kms_key_arn = var.kms_key_arn
  
  s3_settings {
    bucket_folder           = "${var.zones[count.index]}/dms-export/${var.shortApp}"
    bucket_name             = var.bucket_name
    service_access_role_arn = var.service_access_role_arn

  }

  tags = merge(var.tags, { "global.project" = "${local.global_project_tag}" })

   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws dms modify-endpoint --endpoint-arn ${self.endpoint_arn} --extra-connection-attributes ServiceAccessRoleArn=${var.service_access_role_arn};bucketFolder=${var.zones[count.index]}/dms-export/${var.shortApp};bucketName=${var.bucket_name};cannedAclForObjects=BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL;cdcPath=undefined;compressionType=NONE;csvDelimiter=,;csvRowDelimiter=\n;dataFormat=csv;datePartitionEnabled=false;includeOpForFullLoad=true;timestampColumnName=CDCTIMESTAMP"

  }

}
```

The code does not through any error, however not all extra connection attributes are being passed. The result (excerpt from the json response) is this:

```json
"ExtraConnectionAttributes": "ServiceAccessRoleArn=arn:aws:iam::<crossedout>:role/SDP_DMS_MIGRATION_TO_S3_ROLE;bucketFolder=test/dms-export/pc;bucketName=<crossedout>-nonprod-sdp-lz-stag-pnc;cannedAclForObjects=BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL;cdcPath=undefined;compressionType=NONE;csvDelimiter=,;csvRowDelimiter=\\n;datePartitionEnabled=false;",
```

But the other attributes are not passed. There is also no error.

EDIT: AWS CLI WORSK

```sh
aws dms modify-endpoint --endpoint-arn arn:aws:dms:eu-central-1:***********:endpoint:*********** --extra-connection-attributes 'ServiceAccessRoleArn=arn:aws:iam::***********:role/SDP_DMS_MIGRATION_TO_S3_ROLE;bucketFolder=komo/dms-export/pc;bucketName=***********-nonprod-sdp-lz-stag-pnc;cannedAclForObjects=BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL;cdcPath=undefined;compressionType=NONE;csvDelimiter=,;csvRowDelimiter=\n;dataFormat=csv;datePartitionEnabled=false;includeOpForFullLoad=true;timestampColumnName=CDCTIMESTAMP'
```

Comment: Have you been able to prove that the additional connection attributes are not taking effect, i.e. that it's not just a a response completeness issue?

Comment: I can see in the management console as well that they are not there.
When I manually use the AWS CLI, then it works (edited my post).

Comment: What happens if you put the missing attributes first on the extra-connection-attributes option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [cli dms docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/modify-endpoint.html) show the property names. They have different casing than what you're using.

docs show

```
"ServiceAccessRoleArn": "string",
"ExternalTableDefinition": "string",
"CsvRowDelimiter": "string",
"CsvDelimiter": "string",
"BucketFolder": "string",
"BucketName": "string",
"CompressionType": "none"|"gzip",
"EncryptionMode": "sse-s3"|"sse-kms",
"ServerSideEncryptionKmsKeyId": "string",
"DataFormat": "csv"|"parquet",
"EncodingType": "plain"|"plain-dictionary"|"rle-dictionary",
"DictPageSizeLimit": integer,
"RowGroupLength": integer,
"DataPageSize": integer,
"ParquetVersion": "parquet-1-0"|"parquet-2-0",
"EnableStatistics": true|false,
"IncludeOpForFullLoad": true|false,
"CdcInsertsOnly": true|false,
"TimestampColumnName": "string",
"ParquetTimestampInMillisecond": true|false,
"CdcInsertsAndUpdates": true|false,
"DatePartitionEnabled": true|false,
"DatePartitionSequence": "YYYYMMDD"|"YYYYMMDDHH"|"YYYYMM"|"MMYYYYDD"|"DDMMYYYY",
"DatePartitionDelimiter": "SLASH"|"UNDERSCORE"|"DASH"|"NONE"
```

You have:

```
ServiceAccessRoleArn
bucketFolder
bucketName
cannedAclForObjects
cdcPath
compressionType
csvDelimiter
csvRowDelimiter
dataFormat
datePartitionEnabled
includeOpForFullLoad
timestampColumnName
```

Easier view:

```
yours | docs
:-- | :--
bucketFolder         | BucketFolder
bucketName           | BucketName
compressionType      | CompressionType
csvDelimiter         | CsvDelimiter
csvRowDelimiter      | CsvRowDelimiter
dataFormat           | DataFormat
datePartitionEnabled | DatePartitionEnabled
includeOpForFullLoad | IncludeOpForFullLoad
serviceAccessRoleArn | ServiceAccessRoleArn
timestampColumnName  | TimestampColumnName
```

I don't see the following in the docs:

```
CannedAclForObjects
CdcPath
```

putting this all together try:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = format("aws dms modify-endpoint --endpoint-arn %s --extra-connection-attributes %s", self.endpoint_arn, join(";", [
        "ServiceAccessRoleArn=${var.service_access_role_arn}",
        "BucketFolder=${var.zones[count.index]}/dms-export/${var.shortApp}",
        "BucketName=${var.bucket_name}",
        "CannedAclForObjects=BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL",
        "CdcPath=undefined",
        "CompressionType=NONE",
        "CsvDelimiter=,",
        "CsvRowDelimiter=\n",
        "DataFormat=csv",
        "DatePartitionEnabled=false",
        "IncludeOpForFullLoad=true",
        "TimestampColumnName=CDCTIMESTAMP",
    ]))
}
```

This `join` on `;` will also make your command easier to read. It takes that list and combines them with a `;` delimiter.